# Atualização errada em trigger no Oracle

Tags: oracle, trigger

Estou com o seguinte problema na trigger,

Quando há um INSERT na tabela TB_DJE_PREPUBLICACAO, tem que ser verificado se a coluna DT_DISPONIBILIZACAO está nula, se estiver e se a coluna DT_PREPUBLICACAO estiver com a data corrente, a DT_DISPONIBILIZACAO tem que ser preenchida com a data corrente e setada com a hora: 20:00.

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_ATUALIZA_DTDISPONIBILIZAC
BEFORE INSERT ON TB_DJE_PREPUBLICACAO
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.DT_DISPONIBILIZACAO IS NULL)
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        :NEW.DT_DISPONIBILIZACAO := TO_DATE(sysdate || ' 20:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Segue o efeito indesejado na linha 7:

ID_PREPUBLICACAO    DT_PREPUBLICACAO    DT_DISPONIBILIZACAO

1   14/09/2017 10:00    14/09/2017 10:00
2   14/09/2017 11:00    14/09/2017 11:00
3   14/09/2017 12:00    14/09/2017 14:00
4   14/09/2017 18:00    14/09/2017 20:00
5   14/09/2017 09:28    14/09/2017 21:03
6   14/09/2017 08:51    14/09/2017 20:00
7   15/09/2017 08:13    14/09/2017 20:00

Na linha 7, a coluna DT_DISPONIBILIZACAO ficou com a data corrente, sendo que nada deveria ter sido feito, já que é a aplicação que fica responsável por preencher essa coluna, caso a coluna DT_PREPUBLICACAO for posterior à data corrente.

Então, o problema sempre ocorre quando a data DT_PREPUBLICACAO é posterior à data corrente. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: :NEW.DT_DISPONIBILIZACAO := (trunc(sysdate) + (20/24));

Answer (score 0):

A solução seria algo assim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_ATUALIZA_DTDISPONIBILIZAC
BEFORE INSERT ON TB_DJE_PREPUBLICACAO
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.DT_DISPONIBILIZACAO IS NULL)
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        :NEW.DT_DISPONIBILIZACAO := (trunc(sysdate) + (20/24));
    END IF;
END;
```